# Command tab completion of arguments from folder

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

Is it possible to create a list of completions for a command based on some folder's files?

Say I want to run Sublime Text 2 on one of my projects, which are saved as `~/sublime_projects/*.sublime-project`. Desired behaviour:

```
 subl<tab><tab>
   foo bar project2
```

in case there are `foo.sublime-project, bar.sublime-project, project2.sublime-project` files in `~/sublime_projects`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following bash function, add it in you `.bashrc`

Note the directory path for PROJECTS_DIR variable

```bash
# bash completion for sublime projects in ~/projects
_subl()
{
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    PROJECTS_DIR="/home/mreq/projects/"
    LOOK_FOR="*.sublime-project"
    cd ${PROJECTS_DIR}
    PROJECTS=$(ls ${LOOK_FOR})
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${PROJECTS}" -- $cur) )
}
complete -F _subl subl
```

What it does:

- when you type `subl TAB TAB TAB` it lists all projects at the projects directory
- when you type `subl ANY_LETTER TAB` it auto completes the project name if the `ANY_LETTER_TAB` matches with project's first character.

For example if you have inside `~/projects` the following: `test.sublime-project` and `foo.sublime-project` and type `subl t TAB` in terminal you will get `subl test.sublime-project`

**UPDATE** the script bellow does not change the `PWD` i am leaving both for future reference.

```
# bash completion for sublime projects in ~/projects
_subl()
{
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    PROJECTS_DIR="/home/mreq/projects/"
    LOOK_FOR=".sublime-project"
    # cd ${PROJECTS_DIR}
    PROJECTS=$(ls ${PROJECTS_DIR} | grep "^${cur}.*${LOOK_FOR}")
    COMPREPLY=${PROJECTS_DIR}${PROJECTS}
}
complete -F _subl subl
```

The second script looks for a typed character after `subl` and replaces it with the matched filename's full path. For example if there is a `test.sublime-project` in `~/projects` by typing `subl t` will be replaced by `subl /home/USERNAME/projects/test.sublime-project`

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: One thing: This changes your `$PWD` to `$PROJECTS_DIR`. Is there a way to keep the current one? I tried saving it and restoring after `COMPREPLY` assignment, but that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Unfortunately, the second script doesn't work with the blank `<tab>` completions of projects. Using the first one - it's strange, that typing `cd -` after the `$PWD` change was done doesn't get you back to where you were.

Comment: It won't get you back because the script returns. As for the second script, you can pass to subl wildcard * and TAB to list projects but not in a good looking way. Personally i prefer the first script.